# Listing variable values using drush

Tags: 7, drush, features, configuration

I would like to list the values of certain variables using Drush in order to make sure they are in fact the variables that I intend to add to my feature. It seems that some variables are parents which contain multiple children. I use a drush/features/git workflow with a purchased but customized theme and following is my example for clarity.

In my feature `myfeature_theme_helper` there are two variables that I exported to it: `theme__settings` and `theme_settings`. I want to be able to view what values each are storing so I can determine if they should be removed from my helper. One of them contains an active tab, for example, which is not a setting that I want to commit to code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
drush vget theme_THEMENAME_settings
```

it will give you all nested variables but **nested variables  don't work**

```
drush vget theme_THEMENAME_settings.toggle_name 
drush vget theme_THEMENAME_settings:toggle_name
```

so **the only way I found** to get nested variables is with the use of *grep*

so for my theme I would do something like this

```
drush vget theme_THEMENAME_settings | grep toggle_name:
```

or do further processing using cut to get just the value of this variable

```
drush vget theme_THEMENAME_settings | grep toggle_name: | cut -f2- -d:
```

where `theme_THEMENAME_settings` is my variable and `toggle_name` is the nested variable name

Answer (score 1):

Even though I like grep a lot, I think it's worth adding new tools to the toolbox from time to time ;-) Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and JSON output (instead of Yaml that is the default), you can use:

```
drush vget --format=json theme_THEMENAME_settings | jq -r '.theme_THEMENAME_settings | .toggle_name'
```

or the slightly shorter

```
drush vget --format=json theme_THEMENAME_settings | jq -r '.[] | .toggle_name'
```